# Tensorboard: X axis values aren't shown

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

The x axis values (expected them to be the step value) aren't shown in my tensorboard for some unknown reason. Although, when I put my cursor over the graph the step value seems correct. 
Added print screen below.

Anyone got any idea why does is happening?

[image: Print screen of the tensorboard]

Comment: Can you 1) double-click your graph or 2) click the third icon (the one looks like zooming in a window) beneath your graph ?

Comment: 1. I can double-click, doesn't do anything though (unless I'm zoomed in, in which case it zooms out - as usual).
2.All icons are working but there are still no axis values when I zoom or stretch the plot across the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/905

Some people said that using a different browser caused tick marks to show up, another suggested decreasing label font size - however labels also appear to be missing in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my machine. I guess it is related to a new tensorboard release. However, if you change the horizontal axis type from Step to Wall, you get a label for the horizontal axis.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that but wall give you time in the horizontal axis which is usually not what you are interested in.

Comment: On the plus side, when I go from step to wall and back to step, the labels appear for me.